# Displaying the name instead of the id in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm developing a project, where there are two tables, `region` and `district`. In `region` I have:

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | blob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and in `district` I have:

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | blob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region_id   | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the District view, The name of the district gets displayed, but not the Region name:

```
Id  1
Name    Community College
Description Community College
Homepage    
Logo    
Region  ctv.Region : 1
Streams
```

This is the `show` in the `DistrictController`:

```
def show = {
        def districtInstance = District.get(params.id)

        if(!districtInstance){
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'district.label', default: 'District'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action : "list")
        }
        else{
            [districtInstance : districtInstance]
        }
    }
```

How can I modify my `show` closure in other to instead of displaying the `Region.id` I have the `region.name` instead?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are just using the scaffolding?  So try overriding toString() in Region, eg

```
public String toString() {
   name
}
```